# First touch not registered on mobile web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Only on mobile web browsers (both chrome and firefox on iOS), the hamburger menu does not trigger when I tap it the first time.

> Simplified **HTML/CSS/JS** here: https://codepen.io/LayneTrain/pen/vYzZrgv

> Live site: https://key.bio

- I tried forcing the initial property `<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" unchecked />`
- I cannot reproduce this on an emulator.
- This does not happen on desktop web browsers.
- I got rid of all mouseleave/enter events

I am willing to implement a hack just to move past this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that ***not being able to click while scrolling*** is default behavior in mobile.

Since you have to scroll in order to reveal my menu, this behavior was causing my problem.